# Append a json object to a json array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

I have a column in DB of type **json**. The default value of it is [].

Im trying to append a json object to it, and every time it gets updated it will be appended with another json object.

data coming in

```
{"name":"foo", "timestamp": 123}
```

new value in DB should be:

```
[{"name":"foo", "timestamp": 123}]
```

another Update to row:

```
{"name":"john", "timestamp": 234}
```

updated value in row should now be:

```
[{"name":"foo", "timestamp": 123},{"name":"john", "timestamp": 234}]
```

I tried:

```
NEW."dryWeight" = OLD."dryWeight" || NEW."dryWeight";
```

Comment: maybe it is good if you use varchar store you data in string and take it from db change it whatever you want than update it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` operator needs an array on the right if the value on the
left side is an array as well

```
update the_table
   set the_column = the_column || '[{"name":"bar", "timestamp": 234}]'
where ...;
```

`||` only works with the `jsonb`, not with a "plain" `json`

Comment: Thank you, this is how I am trying now:
NEW."dryWeight" = OLD."dryWeight"::jsonb || NEW."dryWeight"::jsonb;
new value i send is in array too, but then updated value is an array with only the latest object, not the object appended to array

Comment: `||` only works with `jsonb`, not `json` what is the actual data type you are using (it should be `jsonb`). You will need to show us your complete trigger function. ([**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62607411/edit) your question, don't put code in comments)